# Use format to print list that can contain an unknown number of variables at run time?

Tags: python, format

The following works when I know that `sample_list` will hold exactly 4 items.

```
sample_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny', 'pig']
print("Your list of animals are: {}, {}, {} and {}".format(*sample_list))
```

How could I format the string if I do not know the number of items that `sample_list` will contain at run time? This would mean that I can't enter the appropriate number of bracket place holders at design time.

Comment: If would probably be easier to just `join` all but the last element with commas, then `join` the last word onto the string with "and".

Comment: However if you require specific formatting for each of the list elements this requires an additional mapping to the formatted elements before joining. You could also generate the format string dynamically by using `len(sample_list)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just use `join`

```
sample_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny', 'pig']
printstr = '%s, and %s' % (', '.join(sample_list[:-1]), str(sample_list[-1]))
print("Your list of animals are: %s" % printstr)
```

Comment: you missed a bracket, and maybe the case with a list of one member can happen

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the Python 3.5+ you can use f-strings like:

```
sample_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny', 'pig']
print(f"Your list of animals are: {', '.join([item for item in sample_list[:-1]])} and {sample_list[-1]}")
```

f-strings are safer than using `%` when inputting data and more flexible than `.format`, for this example it makes no great difference, in my humble opinion one should get used to using them as they are superb :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
sample_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny', 'pig']
str_val = ""
l = len(sample_list) -1

for i, v in enumerate(sample_list):
    if i == l:
        str_val += " and {}".format(v)
    else:
        str_val += " {},".format(v)    

print("Your list of animals are: {}".format(str_val))
```

---

Or one-liner

```
str_val = "".join(" and {}".format(v) if i == l else " {},".format(v) for i, v in enumerate(sample_list))
print("Your list of animals are: {}".format(str_val))
```

**Output:**

```
Your list of animals are:  cat, dog, bunny, and pig
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the string you use `format` on.

```
sample_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny', 'pig']
test='Your list of animals are: '+'{}, '*(len(sample_list)-1)+'and {}'
print(test) # Your list of animals are: {}, {}, {}, and {}
print(test.format(*sample_list)) # Your list of animals are: cat, dog, bunny, and pig
```